# Run length encode

Tags: c++, string, pointers

What does the `sprintf()` line store value to `count` as a `char`? In the `for` loop, `for(k = 0; *(count+k); k++, j++)`, what is `*(count+k)` doing? Can any one explain it?

[image]

```cpp
char *encode(char *src)
{ 
  int rLen;
  char count[100001];
  int len = strlen(src);
  char *dest = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len*2 + 1));
  int i, j = 0, k;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    dest[j++] = src[i];
    rLen = 1;     
    while(i + 1 < len && src[i] == src[i+1])
    {
      rLen++;
      i++;
    }
    sprintf(count, "%d", rLen);
    for(k = 0; *(count+k); k++, j++) //here
    { 
      dest[j] = count[k]; 
    } 
  }
  dest[j] = '\0';
  return dest;
}

int main()
{
  char str[10000];
  cin >> str;
  cout << encode(str) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It means that the author of the code wanted to shine with their fancy knowledge. `*(count + k)` is exactly equivalent to `count[k]`

Comment: Note this code is almost entirely C code. I recommend having a few back-up C++ references if you want to learn C++.

Comment: I guess `sprintf` is just converting an integer to a string(char array).

Comment: Why are you writing this in C, when you're supposed to use C++? C++ makes this stuff way simpler, and less error prone, and performing no worse. Use the language to your benefit! It took so much work to develop it, and the work is already paid for. Leverage it to your advantage! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*(count+k)` is the same as `count[k]` which, when used as a Boolean, is the same as `count[k]!=0`

In plain English, it's a test to see if it has reached the end of the string.

Answer (score -2):

The line " *(count+k) " it's alternate form of " count[k]!='\0' ". This was the exact meaning of this.

Comment: It's not. `*(count+k)` is the same as `count[k]`, and in the context of a conditional (how it is used here) it will be truthy if it is != 0.

Comment: Hmmm... `=` and `==` are very different.

Comment: It is !='\0' @Jan Christoph Terasa